# Android save selected Currency in SharedPreference

Tags: android, save, currency, shared, preference

in my Activity, the user chooses whether to display the currency Canadian or Chinese. I would like to save this choice, I think the best way is to save it in a SharedPreferences. How can I do?

```
 NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.CANADA);
 nf.setCurrency(Currency.getInstance(Locale.getDefault()));

 NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.CHINA);
 nf.setCurrency(Currency.getInstance(Locale.getDefault()));
```

Comment: You already know you need to use SharedPreferences, why don't you look for your answers in using SharedPreferences? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To save:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = getSharedPreferences("currency", MODE_PRIVATE);
sharedPrefs.edit().putString("code", nf.getCurrency().getCurrencyCode()).commit();
```

Then, to restore it:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences("currency", MODE_PRIVATE);
nf.setCurrency(sharedPrefs.getString("code", defaultCurrency));
```

`defaultCurrency` should be the default value. For example:

```
String defaultCurrency = Currency.getInstance(Locale.getDefault()).getCurrencyCode();
```